# jQuery how to stop diagonaly animation after ONE mouseenter?

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".glavna").mouseenter(function(){
    $(".ocenjevanje").animate({right:"+=440", bottom:"+=20"},1000);
    $(".svetovanje").animate({right:"+=440", top:"+140"},1000);
    $(".onas").animate({left:"+=440", top:"+160"},1000);
    $(".infotocka").animate({left:"+=440", bottom:"+3"},1000);
  });
});
```

So now every time i put mouse over my main card (glavna) all others cards move to the side. But how can i make that this will apply only 1 time? I want to move on the main card, all other cards to move to the side and STAY there. How can i achive this?

Comment: can you add your HTML please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var flag=true;
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".glavna").mouseenter(function(){
      if(flag)
      {
         $(".ocenjevanje").animate({right:"+=440", bottom:"+=20"},1000);
         $(".svetovanje").animate({right:"+=440", top:"+140"},1000);
         $(".onas").animate({left:"+=440", top:"+160"},1000);
         $(".infotocka").animate({left:"+=440", bottom:"+3"},1000);
         flag=false;
      }

   });
});
```

Comment: Nope...the cards still slide away after first mouseenter.

Comment: Try the above answer I have made changes in that.

Comment: Thak you very much...that works perfectly.
Can i ask you one more thing? Now i want to put them back on the original position by clicking on main card. I just used same code and replaced mouseenter with click and all left,right,top,bottom values with same negative numbers. And as you could guess its now working...am i at least thinking in the right direction?

Comment: Yes you can try it, but if it not works then you can apply the original position of `divs` like `$(".ocenjevanje").animate({right:"0", bottom:"0"},1000);` if `0` is the original position.

Comment: This isnt working...how do i know what is the original position?
I have the position of all this cards set in css:

.vizitka{
    text-align: left;
    position:relative;
    top:50%;
    margin: 250px auto 0 auto; 
    width: 346px; 
  }

.vizitka-inner {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;

Comment: You can assign the original positions in new variables, then you can use these variables further.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".glavna").one('mouseenter', function(){
    $(".ocenjevanje").animate({right:"+=440", bottom:"+=20"},1000);
    $(".svetovanje").animate({right:"+=440", top:"+140"},1000);
    $(".onas").animate({left:"+=440", top:"+160"},1000);
    $(".infotocka").animate({left:"+=440", bottom:"+3"},1000);
  });
});
```

See [jQuery .one() method](http://api.jquery.com/one/)